# SQL Very Simple Recursive lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server

apologies I know very little about SQL.

I am building some reports which will show nested groups in AD and would like to be able to recurse my dataset and query for a specific group membership. I have about 5000 groups in the table, and only 400 or so are nested.

I've created a simple lookup table, to hold the groups and memberof, and just want to traverse this so when I pass a GroupName to the query it will simply look for all matches of MemberOf=GroupName until Memberof=Null

so here if I wanted to get the nested group details for GRP3 it would return:

GRP3->Grp2->Grp2->Grp4 or Grp3->Grp2->Grp4

for Grp2 it would return : Grp2->Grp4

| GroupName | Memberof |
| --- | --- |
| Grp1 | NULL |
| Grp2 | Grp4 |
| Grp3 | Grp2 |
| Grp4 | Null |
| Grp5 | Grp |

seems very simple, but I just cant figure out.

I found this comprehensive example, but I'm afraid I cant manage to modify it to my needs [How do Recursive CTEs work in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176971/how-do-recursive-ctes-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: Providing table structures, sample data and desired output would make this a LOT easier for people to help. [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is a great location to provide this information.

Comment: ah perfect thank you, sometimes the search doesnt always bring up the best results