# Recursive load for load data with EF Core

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework-core

I have a category entity

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public Category Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I have these records in this table

```
Style (Id = 1, ParentId = null)
    Men (Id = 2, ParentId = 1)
        Shoes (Id = 3, ParentId = 2)
            Sport shoes (Id = 4, ParentId = 3)
```

When I load category page for `Sport shoes`, I want to show breadcrumb for categories like this `Style / Men / Shoes / Sport shoes` have can I get all parents of `Sport shoes` ? 
I know I can use `Include` and `ThenInclude`, but my categories subs is infinite.
Is EF Core support this scenario in built in. if it doesn't please give me TSQL codes for this scenario.

Comment: I doubt EF's ability to give you a performant solution to this type of recursion. Does this thread on [recursive CTEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176971/how-do-recursive-ctes-work-in-sql-server) help get you closer?

Comment: Because this answer is tagged as `tsql` you can use `hierarchyid`, check answer below. @paneerakbari check it out please.

Comment: *please give me TSQL codes* -- Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. There are better tools for that nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Since [EF-8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#sql-server-hierarchyid) you can use TSQL hierarchyid and use TSQL GetAncestor

```cs
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public HierarchyId HierarchyId { get; set; }
}

using var dbContext = new CompanyDbContext();
var categiry_sample = await dbContext.Categories.FindAsync(2);

var manager = 
    await dbContext
    .Categories
    .Where(e =>
        categiry_sample.HierarchyId.IsDescendantOf(e.HierarchyId))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Good article: [Using SQL Server HierarchyId with Entity Framework Core](https://www.meziantou.net/using-hierarchyid-with-entity-framework-core.htm)