# How to generate a specific number of rows using recursive SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate number of rows  in sql, based on one table data in which i have parent child relationship with number of rows in each level.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp3
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    LocationName nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    ParentId INT NULL,
    NumberOfRows INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Temp3 (Id, LocationName, ParentId, NumberOfRows)
VALUES (1, 'Shelve', null, 2)
INSERT INTO #Temp3 (Id, LocationName, ParentId, NumberOfRows)
VALUES (2, 'Rack', 1, 10)
INSERT INTO #Temp3 (Id, LocationName, ParentId, NumberOfRows)
VALUES (3, 'Bin', 2, 20)
```

This query will create a table with data like this:

[image]

I need to generate rows by using above table. For example:

1. Shelve having 2 rows and parent is null, so 2 shelve rows.
2. Rack having 10 rows, but having a parent shelve, which means that every shelve will have 10 rack with parent relation. So in this i will have 20 rows. 10 rows will have relation with 1 shelve and other 10 will have with other shelve. Similar way for Bin.

Could anyone help me out with this.

Output needed:

[image]

Comment: Please include the expected output in your question.

Comment: I have added desired output @TimBiegeleisen, could you please check now

Comment: What's the sql server version you're using? Run `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: Please don't use images use tabular text

Comment: @siggemannen [Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jan  3 2024 16:32:18   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation ]

Comment: @DaleK okay, i will not use images from next time

Comment: No need to wait ...

Comment: And what happen to `Bin`? Why is it not in the result ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Recursive CTEs work in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176971/how-do-recursive-ctes-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi no, it will give me result of existing records only, but here i need to add row dynamically as per the NumberOfRows

Comment: @Squirrel Similar way i need to generate row for Bin, i didn't include it in desired output because if i got the answer for Rack i can implement same for bin.

Comment: Did you try tally tables?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi nope, i don't have idea about tally tables in SQL

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very qucik if you add a tally table with numbers in your database. I always have this type of table into all my databases :

```
CREATE TABLE T_NUM (N INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO T_NUM VALUES (1);
DECLARE @I INT = 1;
WHILE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T_NUM WHERE N = 10000)
   INSERT INTO T_NUM SELECT MAX(N) FROM T_NUM;
```

The the final query is :

```
SELECT T3.* FROM #Temp3 AS T3 JOIN T_NUM ON NumberOfRows >= N
```

Of course other solutions exists but are much slower (recursive queries as an example)

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists #Temp3;
CREATE TABLE #Temp3
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    LocationName nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    ParentId INT NULL,
    NumberOfRows INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Temp3 (Id, LocationName, ParentId, NumberOfRows)
VALUES (1, 'Shelve', null, 2)
INSERT INTO #Temp3 (Id, LocationName, ParentId, NumberOfRows)
VALUES (2, 'Rack', 1, 10)
INSERT INTO #Temp3 (Id, LocationName, ParentId, NumberOfRows)
VALUES (3, 'Bin', 2, 20)


drop table if exists #tbl;
drop table if exists #tbl2;
WITH rcte AS (
    SELECT id ,LocationName,parentid, numberofrows, 1 AS n 
    FROM #Temp3
    WHERE numberofrows > 0 

        --Comment the following line to display all rows
        And id in(1,2) 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id,LocationName,parentid, numberofrows, n + 1
    FROM rcte
    WHERE n < numberofrows

)
Select id,Locationname,parentid Into #tbl From rcte r;
WITH rcte2 AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) idnew,id,Locationname,ParentId,cast(0 as bigint) parentidnew,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) grp
    FROM #tbl
    WHERE ParentId is null

    UNION ALL

    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() over(order by t.id)) idnew,t.id,t.Locationname,t.parentid,Cast(r.idnew as bigint) parentidnew,r.grp
    FROM #tbl t 
        Inner join rcte2 r on r.id= t.ParentId

)
Select (ROW_NUMBER() over(order by grp,parentid)) rownumber,idnew,LocationName,parentidnew into #tbl2 from rcte2;
Select 
    rownumber
    ,LocationName
    ,(Select top 1 t2.rownumber From #tbl2 t2 Where t2.idnew= t.parentidnew And t2.rownumber< t.rownumber And t2.LocationName <> t.LocationName order by t2.rownumber desc)parentid
from #tbl2 t
```